# SQL multiple nested query and alias

Tags: sql, subquery, alias

I have multiple nested queries and I need to add an alias. How can I do it?

This is an example:

```
Select * from table where Value IN (
 Select Value1 from table where Value IN (
  Select Value2 from table where Value IN (
   Select Value3 from table where A = B)))
```

I need to visualize all first select and all `VALUE*`

How can I do this? Maybe with alias ?

Comment: (1) Format your query so it is readable.  (2) Add sample data and desired results so your question makes sense.

Comment: what is your table sturcture ?

Comment: i have many tables, i can't publish db tables

Answer (score 0):

This query has same output. if you are looking for another result please explain more.

```
Select * from table where A = B and Value =Value1 and Value1 =Value2 and Value2 =Value3
```

Comment: i need to do nested query alnd show only some result from each subquery, each table hame more than 10 values for each tables i have more than 6 tables in DB